# Ortsname Beuern

Tags: place-name

Die [Carmina Burana](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmina_Burana) (von denen einige [von Carl Orff vertont](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmina_Burana_(Orff)) wurden) heißen auf deutsch *»Beuersche Lieder«* und sind nach ihrem Fundort *Beuern* benannt. Dieser Fundort heißt heute [Benediktbeuern](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benediktbeuern) und ist ein Kloster, das auch der Gemeinde, in der es liegt, den Namen gab (im Süden Bayerns, nahe der Grenze zu Österreich).

Das Wiener AKH (Allgemeines Krankenhaus) liegt größtenteils auf einem Areal, das [Michelbeuern](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michelbeuern) heißt (das ist auch der Name der nächstgelegenen U-Bahn Station). Dieses Areal gehörte früher der in Salzburg liegenden Benediktinerabtei [Michaelbeuern](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benediktinerabtei_Michaelbeuern).

Es gibt auch mehrere andere Ortschaften, die einen Ortsteil haben, der *»Beuern«* heißt. Wikipedia listet [vier solche Ortsteile](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beuern) auf, von denen zwei in Bayern und zwei in Hessen liegen.

Ich würde nun gerne wissen, was das Wort *»Beuern«* bedeutet, und wovon es abstammt.

Comment: Der im vorletzten Absatz verlinkte Artikel führt direkt zur Antwort von @LangLangC?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Das scheint schnell zu klären zu sein:

> [Beuren](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beuren)  Der Ortsname Beuren (Varianten: -beuern, -beuren, -beuron, -birn, niederdt. -büren, -bur(en) etc.) kommt vom althochdeutschen bur „kleines Haus“ etc., mittelniederländ. buur „Wohnung“, (vergl. Bauer (Vogelkäfig)).